# How to run C# code through a nodejs app on a Linux machine?

Tags: c#, node.js

I want (someone) to build a web app where records can be added. So the app will create a new record with some manual input from a user, but some data is necessary to be retrieved from a file. The parser for this file type is built in C#, however.

Is it possible to: manual input is entered in the app and saved so a new record is created in the database -> file is uploaded through the app -> the app tells the C# code to run, parsing the uploaded file and inserting the data into the database -> the app receives any potential error messages or if the C# program was successful. Or some other logic with with similar result..

Can this be done? Is there some much simpler solution than creating a web app to achieve the same result that I am missing (remotely inputting new records into a database + file uplad + C# parser of this file and then inserting data into the database)?

Thanks

Comment: Would it be easier to look at the c# and remake the parser in node.js?

Comment: Build you C# parser into an `.exe` and call it on a file with `require('shelljs').exec()` or into a simple web server and send it a `require('request')()`

Answer (score 1):

If it is not feasible to rewrite the code in node, you may look at using [`edge`](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) which allows you to access .NET from node.js on Windows, OS X, *and* Linux. The latter two are supported via Mono or CoreCLR.

Comment: As op said `The parser for this file type is built in C#` so it may be a dll which i'm sure is compiled with .Net native and not CoreCLR so it's really a tricky one.

Comment: @vendettamit If that is the case, it would depend on the library. If it's not making platform-specific calls or calls to unimplemented functions in Mono/CoreCLR, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in this topic, but I would think that you could create a very simple listener in C# (not an entire web app, that is bonkers) that accepts requests from your app.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to somehow compile C# to LLVM bytecode, and then use [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki) to convert that to asm.js, which you can just execute using node.

This diagram depicts how it's done with C/C++, but there are some projects out there for doing the same first step with C# instead.  Basically, try to get to a point where you can use emscripten somehow.

[image: Compiler Toolchain]
http://ejohn.org/blog/asmjs-javascript-compile-target/